# No data in Google Analytics (GTM ecomerce setup)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have problems organizing a proper GTM debugging for a new project. I was trying to setup a basic tag from their docs, using:

```
  <script>
// Measure a view of product details. This example assumes the detail view occurs on pageload,
// and also tracks a standard pageview of the details page.
dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'gtm.load',
 'ecommerce': {
   'detail': {
     'actionField': {'list': 'Apparel Gallery'},    // 'detail' actions have an optional list property.
     'products': [{
       'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',         // Name or ID is required.
       'id': '12345',
       'price': '15.25',
       'brand': 'Google',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'variant': 'Gray'
      }]
    }
  }
});
console.log("Pushed");
 </script>
```

as tracking code, and also setting up the basic GTM tag, as suggested by the example: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#details

And using the Window Loaded event type for trigger.

The gtm debugger shows that events are triggered.. But nothing appears in google analytics.

I was also checking, if some messages are being sent to GA using the firebug, and looks like they are sent:

```
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j47d&a=681300097&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.107%2F%3Fproduct%3Dtest-product&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=test%20product&sd=24-bit&sr=1366x768&vp=1351x415&je=0&fl=22.0%20r0&_u=SCCAAAALI~&jid=&cid=247695807.1477915334&tid=UA-73812011-1&gtm=GTM-TWQ9DJ&pal=Apparel%20Gallery&pa=detail&pr1nm=Triblend%20Android%20T-Shirt&pr1id=12345&pr1pr=15.25&pr1br=Google&pr1ca=Apparel&pr1va=Gray&z=280618779
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options here, depending on how much control you have with the page code. If you have full control, and if you want you load the ecom data on page load, then you do a dataLayer declaration with that data just before your GTM container:

```
dataLayer = [{
   'ecommerce': {
      'detail': {
        'actionField': {'list': 'Apparel Gallery'},    // 'detail' actions have an optional list property.
       'products': [{
         'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',         // Name or ID is required.
          'id': '12345',
          'price': '15.25',
          'brand': 'Google',
          'category': 'Apparel',
          'variant': 'Gray'
       }]
     }
   }
}];
```

Doing it this way allows you to capture the data on page load with your pageview tag.

You shouldn't do it with an event push, not especially with an event named `gtm.load` as that is the built-in event that gets pushed when the page assets have completely loaded, so you are probably not seeing data as there is a conflict with your 'page load' since there are now two `gtm.load` events being pushed.

If you still prefer an event, then just use a different name, eg. `myEvent`, and then create an event tag to fire on that event.

Lastly don't forget to enable your tag to use the dataLayer in order to capture the ecom info.

Comment: I have tried to to the change above (moved the dataLayer above, and removing the push and event). But still is not getting anything in GA. I wonder if it may be related to the fact that I am testing from localhost( but I still see myself in realtime dashboard, but not the events)

Comment: There is not ecommerce data available in Real-Time, but you could use GA Debugger to see the hit go through though.